Robot Framework + SauceLabs - configuration Open Browser : No browserName or device specified in session request, BUT IT DOES
I adapted configuration for new version of Selenium as it was described in official documentation, but it doesn't work
openBrowserEdge.py:
@library
class openBrowserEdge:
    @keyword('Open Edge')
    def open_edge(self):
        
        options = EdgeOptions()
        options.browser_version = '123'
        options.platform_name = 'Windows 11'
        options.accept_insecure_certs = True
        options.unhandled_prompt_behavior = 'accept and notify'

        sauce_options = {}
        sauce_options['username'] = '***'
        sauce_options['accessKey'] = '***'
        sauce_options['name'] = 'Update Open Browser'
        sauce_options['screenResolution'] = '800x600'
        sauce_options['videoUploadOnPass'] = False
        sauce_options['extendedDebugging'] = True

        options.set_capability('sauce:options', sauce_options)

        return options

Test Suite:
Simple Open
    ${opts}    openNavig.Open Edge Navigateur
    Open Browser    ${url}    browser=edge   remote_url=${saucelabsUrl}   options=${opts}


It shows an error: "WebDriverException: Message: No browserName or device specified in session request. Please check our platforms documentation (https://saucelabs.com/docs/platforms): {}      "
the link to documentation returns 404
I send "browserName" in Open Browser Keyword and I don't need to specify "device" as it is desktop
Could you help me to reconfigurate , please ?
